# Enter does nothing in NeoTree

Tags: key-bindings, navigation, neotree

I have NeoTree  installed. When I navigate through folders and files in it and when I press **enter**, nothing happens. I don't get into a directory. I've tried TAB also -- nothing.

M-x describe-key Enter

[image]

Comment: `C-h k` and `enter`; or, `M-x describe-key` and `enter`.  What function is being called?

Comment: @lawlist, what's that supposed to tell me?

Comment: @lawlist updated

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what the default is supposed to be -- see https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/blob/dev/neotree.el#L609  You may want to try with no user-configuration whatsoever and just install neotree and see if it works as it should.  Then, if it works with no user-configuration, you may need to recursively bisect your user-configuration by crossing stuff out, saving and restarting Emacs until you find what is messing up the default binding.

Answer (score 0):

If the results of `C-h k` and `enter`; or, `M-x describe-key` and `enter`, do not match step number 8 hereinbelow, then ... consider recursively bisecting the user-configuration files by crossing stuff out, saving and restarting Emacs until the offending code is isolated.  Troubleshooting shortcuts may include, but are not limited to, seeing what minor-modes are active in the `*NeoTree*` buffer that might be causing a conflict -- e.g., type `C-h m` or `M-x describe-mode` to see the minor-modes that are active; and, try disabling those minor-modes that look like they could be the root cause of the problem.

---

Troubleshooting problems with Neotree **without** any user-configuration.

(1.)  Launch a current version of Emacs (e.g., 25.3) and switch to the `*scratch*` buffer.

(2.)  Type (or copy/paste) in the `*scratch*` buffer:

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

(3.) `M-x eval-buffer`

(4.) `M-x list-packages`

(5.) `M-x package-refresh-contents`

(6.)  Select `neotree` and install it.

(7.)  `M-x neotree`

(8.)  Switch to the `*NeoTree*` buffer.  Place the cursor on a directory.  Type: `C-h k` and `enter`; or, `M-x describe-key` and `enter`.  The result should be:

```
RET (translated from <return>) runs the command #[(&optional arg)
"\301 \210\302\303\304#\207" [arg neo-global--select-window
neo-buffer--execute neo-open-file neo-open-dir] 4 nil "P"] (found in
neotree-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

It is bound to RET.

(anonymous &optional ARG)

Not documented.
```